# Can Lambda expression be downgraded to C++ 98

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++98

I recently got a problem need to integrate C++ 11 code written with lambda expression to old code base which only support C++ 98 compiler. I figured out couple of possible equivalences of lambda like Macro, functor or function pointer. But seems they are all limited when translating lambda with capture. For example a simple generic function with call back:

```
template <class Fn>  
void ForEachObject(Fn fn)  
{  
    for (uint i = 0; i < objectCount; i++)  
    {  
        fn(i, address + i * objectSize);  
    }  
}
```

and the typical caller will do something like:

```
uint attributes = 0x0030;
....
ForEachObject([=](uint index, void * objectAddress)
{
    if ((ObjectInfo(index) & attributes) != 0)
    {
        fn(index, objectAddress);
    }
});
```

Note attributes here is come from out of the scope of lambda. Is there anyway to still reuse the for each logic without lambda? Or I must re-write the logic on every such caller?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are after. You only capture an `uint` here. You could just add the parameter and make the function standalone. What logic do you want to reuse, if you change the parameter type, the logic inside would also change.

Comment: It's a just sample caller, different callers will pass different local variables into the lambda scope. In that case, the only way is writing an standalone function for lambda part and pass these capture as parameter. right? I'm new on lambda. so just want figure if any way better to do it.

Comment: If you tell your compiler, perhaps we can work something out

Comment: Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 for 80x86

Comment: @milleniumbug Boost is not an option in my project. But thank you.

Comment: @bin3377 you sure that's the compiler you're using? Because that would correspond to VS2010 which does support lambdas (just not C++14 generic lambdas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Functor:

```
struct Functor
{
    explicit Functor(uint attributes) : attributes(attributes) {}
    void operator () (uint index, void * objectAddress) const
    {
        if ((ObjectInfo(index) & attributes) != 0)
        {
            fn(index, objectAddress);
        }
    }
    uint attributes;
};
```

And then call

```
uint attributes = 0x0030;
// ....
ForEachObject(Functor(attributes));
```

For each different lambda, you have to write a functor.
You don't have to modify `ForEachObject`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the problem is not every caller will use 'attributes', it's just a sample. Do you means for every caller should write a individual Functor to pass-in all necessary captures?

Comment: @bin3377 Yes, you make a new Functor for each lambda. That's how the internal implementation probably works.

Comment: @bin3377 You can declare a functor inside a function (just before usage), which is almost as trivial as using a lambda and is better to debug in some compilers.

Comment: @DieterLücking Thank you! I think that's the way I definitely want go with.

Comment: @bin3377 if you are OK with local classes (defined inside a function) and your compiler accepts that (that was forbidden by C++03), and use Clang or GCC, you can use statement expressions: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ec02c173c2e8097 .

Answer (score 2):

> Can Lamda expression be downgrade to C++ 98

No they cannot. Prior C++11 standards have no notion of lambda syntax.

Though there are surrogates available like [`boost::lambda`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/lambda.html)

You can provide *functor style* classes, overriding the call operator (`<return_type> operator()(<args>);`), to provide the same effect, as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Although I already upvoted, it would be a better answer if you could provide a short example in your answer.

Comment: Yes, a usable / generic example would earn you an upvote from me.